how to run chancel_build and panel_hide with single shortcut in sublime text wihtout macro
I hope someone can help me.I am using Sublime Text 4 b.4180 under Fedora 40.
following scenario:
When I run a build and want to cancel it, I want the escape button to execute cancel_build and hide_panel. but if the program exits successfully without being canceled, the panel is visible and does not close when I press escape. the following setting:
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "build" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+#"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+escape"], "command": "cancel_build" },
    {
     "keys": ["escape"],
    "context": [
        { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["cancel_build"],
            ["hide_panel", {"cancel": true}]
        ]
    }
}
]

in the second setting. here everything works as i imagine, but when i press escape the panel is closed, but the build is still running in the background.
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "build" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+#"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+escape"], "command": "cancel_build" },
    {
        "keys": ["escape"],
        "context": [
            { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ],
        "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"cancel": true}
    },
    {
        "keys": ["escape"],
        "context": [
            { "key": "find_panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ],
        "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"cancel": true}
    }
]

does anyone have a solution as to how I can make both settings work in a single file?
also: the toggle_comment shortcut sometimes works. but sometimes it just doesn't do anything. maybe it's a fedora problem, maybe just a bug in st. if someone can help i would be very grateful
